# Join the result of 2 queries(make it in 1 query preferable)

Tags: c#, mysql

So i have 2 queries who get the score of a football team from 1 table

Query 1

```
SELECT SUM(Score_Thuis) FROM `wedstrijden` WHERE `Gespeeld` = 1 AND Thuis_team = 'Team 14'
```

Query 2

```
SELECT SUM(Score_Uit) FROM `wedstrijden` WHERE `Gespeeld` = 1 AND Uit_team = 'Team 14'
```

Is there a way i can get 1 query and get the result of the above 2.
I have experienced alot with the SUM command but all it did was combine the score of the opponents team aswell or give result in 2 rows :/

Comment: `SELECT .... UNION SELECT ....` potentially, but this question is a bit vague

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(Score_Thuis), SUM(Score_Uit)
FROM wedstrijden
WHERE `Gespeeld` = 1 AND (Thuis_team = 'Team 14' OR Uit_team = 'Team 14')
```

Comment: When i use this the result i get is 2 rows which includes the score of both teams, team 14 and their opponent.

Comment: @Taacoo What I have just re-done your query as you have suggested. Your question is particularly not very clear, and thats why you have recieved 5 downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT SUM(Score_Thuis) 
   FROM `wedstrijden` 
   WHERE `Gespeeld` = 1 AND Thuis_team = 'Team 14' AND Uit_team = 'Team 14'
```